# Dependency injection in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Please help me describe how the below code achieving the dependency injection.

```
function MyController($scope, myService) {
  $scope.message = myService.getMessage();
}
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'myService', MyController]);
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('myService', function() {
    return {
      getMessage: function() {
        return 'Hello, world!';
      }
    };
  });
```